# Adding Next Number to Previous number in Vector in R, For Loop

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I am super new to coding and am trying to make a little for loop in R. The idea is to add each subsequent index in the numbers loop and output it to a new vector called sums. So, the sums vector should look like (10,19,27,34,40,45,49,52,54,55).

```
numbers<-seq(10,1, by=-1)
Output: [1] 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
sums<-c()
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
for (i in numbers) {
  sums[i]<-sum(numbers[i+1])
  print(sums)
}

Output: [1]  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 NA NA

for (i in numbers) {
  sums[i]<-sum(numbers[i})
  print(sums)
}

Output: 55
```

Comment: `sums[1] <- numbers[1];for(i in seq(2, length(numbers)) sums[i] <- sums[i - 1] + numbers[i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do this

```
sums <- cumsum(10:1)
sums
```

If you want to use a `for` loop, you could do something like this:

e.g.

```
numbers<- 10:1

# this creates a blank vector
sums <- c()

for (i in seq_along(numbers)) {
  sums <-c(sums, sum(numbers[1:i]))
}

print(sums)
```

If you put print inside the loop, it's going to print at every iteration of the loop

Comment: This was it! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the cumulative sum function

cumsum(10:1)